# Use VB.Net for Excel scripting

Tags: excel, vb.net

I understand it is very well possible to write scripts in VB.Net which are able to create/manipulate Excel application and its object structure. Is there a workaround that would allow one to include or otherwise integrate the VB.Net code into a particular workbook so that a regular user could run it? E.g.:

- Having the script in VB.Net in a separate file next to the Excel file and call it through VBA.
- Inserting the VB.Net script file into the workbook (like one can insert any other file) and then running it by double-clicking it

The aim is to go around some of the limitations and archaisms of VBA as well as being able to use some more modern and user-friendly IDE (such as VSCode) instead of the built-in VBE.

Comment: No, Excel can only store VBA macros in a workbook.  The execution environment for VB.NET code is fundamentally different, it is useful to write an add-in or automate Excel with a separate program.

Comment: You can write exported DLL functions in a non-.NET language and then call them from VBA.  Reasonable choices for the purpose include C++ and Fortran.  Remember that your function needs to be stdcall for VBA to be able to call it, and if you're going to use multi-dimensional arrays, VBA uses a column-major memory layout (opposite from C++, same as Fortran).